# JPA save/update only if modifications

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, repository, entitymanager

I have a problem, with the Spring JPA, I did not find anything about saving entity only if there are modification. And I am not talking about saving certain fields.

After the database data is loaded by the JPA entity manager, how can I verify, before I save the entity, if there are modification/changes to the fields. Without taking each field and verify it with:
         if (field != ...)

```
    Class i = repo.findByExternalId(externalId);

    ...

    if (modifications)
       repo.save(i);
     else
       //don't save
```

I tried with dynamic-update=true but it doesn't work.

If you have some information about what to search on the web... that would be helpful as well.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have appropriate `hashCode`/`equals` implementations, the ORM should take care of it automatically. You can just call `save` and that will translate to database activity only when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't call `save()` but put everything in one transaction.

JPA will do the checking for you and save changes if necessary.